# Multiple TeraData cutsom queries to individual blob CSV files usinf Azure Data Factory

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I am very much new to Azure Data Factory.
I would like to know how to copy data from Teradata multiple queries(around 6 custom queries) to .csv files in Blob container using ADF.

I have referred documents, but I can copy data from tables , not from multiple custom queries.
If you could give me step by step instructions, that would help me a lot to learn.

Thanks!!

Comment: Hi TechSavy, If my answer is helpful for you, you can accept it as answer( click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.). This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

When Teradata as source, it has the **query** property:
[image]

Ref：https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-teradata#teradata-as-source

We use the query property to run your custom queries. Click the **Query** operation and put query in the box. I just guess your query across more tables.

[image]

Hope this helps.